# How to plot a arrow on time using the x axis?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to get an arrow line on the plot using time ie 10:30:00. I had tried various formats of date & time but am getting the following error "naa_8c.plt" line 21: undefined variable: set. The script plots the data OK without the arrow command.
How do I define the variable to be used with the arrow command?

Program script

```
clear

reset

set xdata time

set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M'

set format x "%H:%M"

set datafile separator ","
set key left top
set title "Test Title" font "sans, 14" 
set ylabel "ylable title"
set xlabel "UT Time"
set autoscale y  
set ytics textcolor rgb "blue"
set grid

plot '2018-03-02 naa x ray.csv' u 1:4 w lines lt rgb "red" ,set arrow from "103000",graph 0 to "103000",graph 1 nohead lt 2 lc rgb 'red' lw 2

replot
```

Data file `2018-03-02 naa x ray.csv`

```
Date,time,Short,NAA-24k

2018-03-02,00:00:29,2.87E-08,-86.4332
2018-03-02,00:01:30,0.000000027,-86.6562
2018-03-02,00:02:29,2.83E-08,-86.5777
2018-03-02,00:03:30,2.55E-08,-86.5437
2018-03-02,00:04:30,0.000000031,-86.6023
2018-03-02,00:05:29,3.02E-08,-86.7367
2018-03-02,00:06:30,3.05E-08,-86.6627
2018-03-02,00:07:29,2.55E-08,-86.5023
2018-03-02,00:08:30,2.73E-08,-86.6553
2018-03-02,00:09:29,2.81E-08,-86.6298
2018-03-02,00:10:30,2.75E-08,-86.4740
2018-03-02,00:11:29,2.74E-08,-86.5313
```

A lot more data in file

I have tried using various formats of date & or time getting the same error. I have searched the web but have been unable to find a solution that works, they all seem to use the date and not the time.

I am wanting a line on the plot at the time set in the variable, the line is being used as a marker on the plot.

Comment: You try to set an arrow within the plot command.This will not work. Use the plotting style `with vectors`. check `help vectors`. Later today I will give an example if still necessary.

Comment: I have done a Google search and an unable to find an example that uses the time, ie 10:30 they are all using a hole number. Are you saying I can’t use time to put a line on the plot?

Comment: an arrow has a startpoint and an endpoint or a startpoint and direction and length. From where to where do you want to draw your `10:30` arrow?

Comment: I understand now, I will look for another solution to the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to draw a vertical line from the bottom of the graph to the top of the graph at a given time position on the x-axis.

In the example below I'm using the syntax without `set xdata time`. Then you have to use `timecolumn()`, check `help timecolumn` and `help strptime`.

This is ok if you know your x-value in advance. However, if you want to determine the x-position automatically from your data (e.g. at minimum y-value), you have to add a few lines.

**Script:**

```
### set an arrow on time axis
reset session

$Data <<EOD
Date,time,Short,NAA-24k
2018-03-02,00:00:29,2.87E-08,-86.4332
2018-03-02,00:01:30,0.000000027,-86.6562
2018-03-02,00:02:29,2.83E-08,-86.5777
2018-03-02,00:03:30,2.55E-08,-86.5437
2018-03-02,00:04:30,0.000000031,-86.6023
2018-03-02,00:05:29,3.02E-08,-86.7367
2018-03-02,00:06:30,3.05E-08,-86.6627
2018-03-02,00:07:29,2.55E-08,-86.5023
2018-03-02,00:08:30,2.73E-08,-86.6553
2018-03-02,00:09:29,2.81E-08,-86.6298
2018-03-02,00:10:30,2.75E-08,-86.4740
2018-03-02,00:11:29,2.74E-08,-86.5313
EOD

set datafile separator comma

myTimeFmt = "%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M" timedate
myMarker = strptime(myTimeFmt,"2018-03-02,00:05:29")

set arrow 1 from myMarker, graph 0 to myMarker, graph 1 lw 2 lc "red" nohead

plot $Data u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):4 w l ti "Data"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I will know the time I need to draw the line in advance. A big thanks for your help and your example will give me something to work with. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Peter if it solved your problem, please accept the answer indicating that the problem is solved. Othewise, please specify in more detail what is still missing.

Comment: It has solved my problem and have accepted the answer.